# How do I set up Magento 2.3.3 with a sandbox Auth.net account?

Tags: magento2.3.3, authorize.net, json, sandbox-mode

Using Magento 2.3.3, I've set up a sandbox Auth.net account, and added the API Login ID, Transaction Key, Public Client Key and Signature Key to the admin configuration, enabled the Payment Method and cleared the cache.

On checkout, selecting the Auth.net payment method and clicking 'Place Order', I'm getting an error displayed on the payment page:

```
User authentication failed due to invalid authentication values.
```

But I'm seeing a different error in the requests to the API:

```
Request URL: https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Response:

```
{"messages":{"resultCode":"Error","message":[{"code":"E00001","text":"Error reading JToken from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0."}]}}
```

I guess this could be a result of the configuration, but afaict, there's nothing further required than the above.

Comment: I'm running into this with production credentials but only for one Auth.net account.

Comment: I've filed a bug with Magento - apparently it's happening with 2.4-develop as well: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26376

Comment: Is there a workaround or fix?

Comment: Sadly not that I'm aware of @Marisa

Comment: It looks like the entire core Auth.net module has been deprecated with 2.3.4 per the Release Notes: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-4-open-source.html  - "The core integration of the Authorize.net payment method has been deprecated. Please use the official payment integration that is available on Marketplace."

Comment: I'm getting this same error with the Authorize.net module available on the marketplace.

Comment: As am I so I cannot tell if this is from Magento 2 or if it's on the Auth.net end.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue in Magento 2.3.4 and authorize.net production environment  that I have downloaded authorize.net official extension from Magento marketplace and install then also found the same issue.

After debugging, I have found error due to the special character in the line item.

Authorize.net accept only 30 characters in the line item name field, but when use PHP substr function it can't work for arebic charectore and all request parameter become blank due to this error

I have changed in below file

**AuthorizeNet\Core\Gateway\Request\AbstractRequestBuilder**

line number 171

**form**

```
$formattedName = substr($item->getName(), 0, 31);
```

**to**

```
$formattedName = mb_substr($item->getName(), 0, 31, 'utf-8');
```

After this changes payment method working fine